# Information lost in Xpad

Tags: ubuntu

My Xpad has been fine until a couple of weeks ago. I noticed when I **Close and Save Pad** and re-open it, some post-it were missing. I saved 3 slides but only 1 was recovered. And sometimes, the reopened slide is only partially recovered. Anyone else encounter the same problem? Is this an Xpad problem or a setup issue? My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 14):

Right click on an open XPad Note, or create a new one then right click on the new Note, then click on NOTES. Now one by one click and open any of your missing notes.

Edit: Or click on Show All

Answer (score 3):

STOP!  Backup right now!

I tried DaveQ's suggestion, but at first it did not work.

This [Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458977/where-is-the-xpad-content-stored-on-disk) showed me thatXpad saves its notes in ~/.config/xpad.  I found all my note contents in the *content-** files which appear to be simple ASCII files.  I created ~/.backup/xpad and copied all my content-* files there.

After killing and restarting xpad, I found that DaveQ's instructions worked, and I was able to re-open my notes (before they got deleted somehow.)